# Is it possible to use apache's URIBuilder to set a parameter with percentage sign?

Tags: urlencode, uribuilder

I want to build this complete URL:

```
locahost/some/path?param1=%06
```

using `org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` method `setParameter(final String param, final String value)`. At its javadoc, there's line:

```
The parameter name and value are expected to be unescaped and may contain non ASCII characters
```

But when I use `setParameter("param1","%06")` I always get `...param1=%2506` instead of `...param1=%06`. [Looking here](http://www.asciitable.com/) I noticed percent sign is 25 in hex.

Should I parse this manually or there's a way to keep using `URIBuilder` and keep the parameters as is?